# Alignment of control widgets on fluidPage in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app, but ran into a problem with the placement of widgets depending on the size of the browser window. I am using nested column and fluidRow to place my widgets (see code below). I want the left side of widgets B and D aligned, and the right side of B and E (see Fig 1), but when I increase the size of the window, at some point the alignment of the right side doesn't hold anymore (Fig 2).

Fig 1: correct layout
[image: correct layout]

Fig 2: incorrect layout
[image: incorrect layout]

Here is a reproducible example:
ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(column(
6,fluidRow(column(6, numericInput("a", label = "A", 0)),
           column(6, numericInput("b", label = "B", 0))),
fluidRow(
    column(6, numericInput("c", label = "C", 0)),
    column(3, numericInput("d", label = "D", 0)),
    column(3, numericInput("e", label = "E", 0))
)
 ),
 column(5, offset=1,h1("other stuff"))
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

Comment: You need to set the width of B to something larger, e.g. `width = 100%`.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks, this is helpful! But in this case, my B widget will "grow" longer than A, however I want to keep them the same size. If I add `width=100%` to widget A, then they will have the same size, but now both of them will "grow" long on the screen, however originally the space between them grew. Is there a way to constrain my 2nd row of widgets not to "grow" further and not change the first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, here are some suggestions:

1) Fix your `numericInputs` to 100% width. Alle Inputs will be looking lengthy, but at least you have total control over input size vs. column size.

Code to copy:

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(column(
        6,fluidRow(column(6, numericInput("a", label = "A", 0, width = '100%')),
                   column(6, numericInput("b", label = "B", 0, width = '100%'))),
        fluidRow(
            column(6, numericInput("c", label = "C", 0, width = '100%')),
            column(3, numericInput("d", label = "D", 0, width = '100%')),
            column(3, numericInput("e", label = "E", 0, width = '100%'))
        )),
        column(5, offset=1,h1("other stuff"))
    ))
```

2) Use a `fixedPage` layout. This makes stretching less "nice", but if you dont suspect your users to be changing page sizes all the time, it might be a valid choice.

Code to copy:

```
    shinyUI(fixedPage(column(
        6,fixedRow(column(6, numericInput("a", label = "A", 0)),
                   column(6, numericInput("b", label = "B", 0))),
        fixedRow(
            column(6, numericInput("c", label = "C", 0)),
            column(3, numericInput("d", label = "D", 0)),
            column(3, numericInput("e", label = "E", 0))
        )),
        column(5, offset=1,h1("other stuff"))
    ))
```

3) This is probably closest to what you were looking for. As it happens, `column(...)` takes additional arguements, which can be used to influence style with html-like attributes. So `column(3, ..., align = 'right')` aligns your column to the right border (of its parent column!). But, since your Input "B" eventually becomes smaller, than the actual column width, this doesn't help much unless you again fix "B"s width to 100% = full column width.

Code to copy:

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(column(
        6, fluidRow(column(6, numericInput("a", label = "A", 0)),
                    column(6, numericInput("b", label = "B", 0, width = '100%'))),
        fluidRow(
          column(6, numericInput("c", label = "C", 0)),
          column(3, numericInput("d", label = "D", 0)),
          column(3, numericInput("e", label = "E", 0), align = 'right')
        )),
        column(5, offset=1,h1("other stuff"))
    ))
```

I hope this somehow answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks! The fixedPage layout fits perfectly with my application, especially because the navbar is also nicely aligned now to the page content.