# How to align different input fields in Shiny (vertical offset/padding/alignment)?

Tags: r, shiny

New to shiny. I'm creating a data exploration app for some experimental data.

I first select a variable to subset by and then use sliders to select a range for the said variables (shown in image). The subsetted data is overlaid on the original plot in red.

[image]

I want the `sliderInput` to be aligned at the same level as the `selectInput`. What's the best way to do that? I also want to add a checkbox or radio button for these variables which if selected would add a secondary plot (or secondary axis - I know, not recommended but that's what is desired). I haven't implemented that yet but putting that here since that would require the same aligning.

**CODE**

The arguments of `sliderInput` and `selectInput` have been removed for brevity. `zdat()` is a reactive `data.table`.

*UI*

```
fluidRow(
    column(4,
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_x"), # Select x-axis for SortZoomPlot
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_y"), # Select y-axis for SortZoomPlot 
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_var1"), # Subset data by var1 
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_var2"), # Subset data by var2
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_var3") # Subset zoomplot data by var3
           ),

    column(4,
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_var1_slider"), # range for subsetZoomPlot_var1 (slider input)
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_var2_slider"), # range for subsetZoomPlot_var1 (slider input)
           uiOutput("subsetZoomPlot_var3_slider") # range for subsetZoomPlot_var1 (slider input)
    )
  ),

  fluidRow(
    plotOutput("subsetZoomPlot")
  )
```

*SERVER*

```
output$subsetZoomPlot_x <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "subsetZoomPlot_x", ...)
  })

  output$subsetZoomPlot_y <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "subsetZoomPlot_y", ...)
  })

  output$subsetZoomPlot_var1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "subsetZoomPlot_var1", ...)
  })

  output$subsetZoomPlot_var2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "subsetZoomPlot_var2", ...)
  })

  output$subsetZoomPlot_var3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "subsetZoomPlot_var3", ...)
  })

  output$subsetZoomPlot_var1_slider <- renderUI({
    vmin <- floor(min(zdat()[, get(input$subsetZoomPlot_var1)]))
    vmax <- ceiling(max(zdat()[, get(input$subsetZoomPlot_var1)]))
    sliderInput(...)
  })

  output$subsetZoomPlot_var2_slider <- renderUI({
    vmin <- floor(min(zdat()[, get(input$subsetZoomPlot_var2)]))
    vmax <- ceiling(max(zdat()[, get(input$subsetZoomPlot_var2)]))
    sliderInput(...)
  })

  output$subsetZoomPlot_var3_slider <- renderUI({
    vmin <- floor(min(zdat()[, get(input$subsetZoomPlot_var3)]))
    vmax <- ceiling(max(zdat()[, get(input$subsetZoomPlot_var3)]))
    sliderInput(...)
  })
```

EDIT: 
I added my current code for the UI section. It already has `fluidrow(column(), column())` for the layout. My problem is that I want the slider for `var1` (`rh` in the screenshot) to be aligned at the same level as the dropdown where `rh` is selected (`selectInput`) and the same for the other two variables. This means the second column needs to be vertically displaced. Is the only way to do this using multiple `fluidrow` statements for each combination of `selectInput` and `sliderInput`?

Comment: Element alignment is a matter of UI, so you'd be better off sharing your UI rather than your server. In any case, you should [read this guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html), especially the section on the [fluid grid system](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html#fluid-grid-system).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alignment of control widgets on fluidPage in shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040781/alignment-of-control-widgets-on-fluidpage-in-shiny-r)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that question is more for the horizontal alignment. I'm trying to find a way to get the vertial alignment right without having create a new row for each line of input variables and sliders. That is, if it is possible to have vertical padding/offset.

Answer (score 1):

All of the layout issues are things that need to be addressed in the UI section of your shiny app code.

From what I can tell it looks like the code you've included with your question is in the server section since it seems that you have dynamic inputs in your app.

Here is some simple UI code that aligns a select input with a slider input

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(title = 'Example',

            fixedRow(
              column(width = 2,
                     selectInput('input1_choice', 'Select Plot variable 1',
                                 choices = letters[11:20])),
              column(width = 2,
                     sliderInput('input1_val', 'Select Variable 1 Value',
                                 0, 10, 5)
              )
            ),
            fixedRow(
              column(width = 2,
                     selectInput('input2_choice', 'Select Plot variable 2',
                                 choices = letters[1:10])
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     sliderInput('input2_val', 'Select Varaible 2 Value',
                                 0, 10, 5)
              )
            )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

So each fixedRow call creates a  row in the UI, and each column call within a fixedRow call creates a column in that row to fill with a UI object.

As you change the types of UI objects the height of that row can change but it won't overlap or bleed into another row demonstrated here:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(title = 'Example',

            fixedRow(
              column(width = 2,
                     selectInput('input1_choice', 'Select Plot Variable 1',
                                 choices = letters[11:20])),
              column(width = 2,
                     radioButtons('input1_val', 'Select Variable 1 Value',
                                 choices = LETTERS[11:20])
              )
            ),
            fixedRow(
              column(width = 2,
                     selectInput('input2_choice', 'Select Plot Variable 2',
                                 choices = letters[1:10])
              )
            ),
            fixedRow(
              column(width = 2,
                     selectInput('input3_choice', 'Select Plot Variable 3',
                                 choices = letters[1:10])
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     sliderInput('input3_val', 'Select Variable 3 Value',
                                 0, 10, 5)
              )
            )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

The only difference between these examples and what you'll need is to replace the explicit UI object calls I've made (selectInput for example) with uiOutput calls.

Like some comments have said there's documentation out there. I've found https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/ to be especially useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have `fluidrow` in my UI code. It's more for the vertical alignment - I want the dropdown for a variable and slider for the variable to be at the same level i.e. slider for `rh` would be adjacent to the dropdown where `rh` is selected.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post images in answers but here's a screen cap of the UI output from the second block of code, let me know if that is what you're looking for https://imgur.com/a/XRj3s

Comment: I used multiple `fluidrow` statements to create this screen: https://imgur.com/a/WInOO but it's tedious to do that. Still looking for vertical padding. Here's a screenshot of my current ui code: https://imgur.com/a/Zh7WC

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the best solution, but you can use columns in your UI :

```
fluidRow(
column(4,selectInput("select_x", "Select X Axis", ...)),
column(8),
column(4,selectInput("select_y", "Select Y Axis", ...)),
column(8)
column(4, selectInput("subsetZoomPlot_var1", ...)),
column(4, sliderInput(...)),
column(4),
column(4, selectInput("subsetZoomPlot_var2", ...)),
column(4, sliderInput(...)),
column(4),
...
)
```